# PHP function fails to append results

Tags: php, function

This is my function
http://www.ideone.com/slpPe

If i don't use function

```
    preg_match_all("{http://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}[^\s\"\\\'\<&]*}ix", $html, $marches);
    $download = $marches[0];
//var_dump();
    $i = 0;
    for ($i; $i <= count($download); $i++) {
        echo  "download|";
        $links = $download[$i];
        if (!eregi("avaxhome.ws|pixhost.info", $links)) {
            echo  $links . "<br/>";
        }
    }
```

and return some link

```
download|
```

http://www.filesonic.com/file/24394419/1851684883.rar

http://depositfiles.com/files/g6wawevha

Please help me fix it

Comment: To help fix it we need to know what it should do and what it is doing.

Comment: I want echo all download link in $html1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

```
for ($i; $i <= count($download); $i++) {

 // You are re-initializing $return in the loop..overwriting it.
  $return = "download|";
```

Just move the initilization outside the loop as:

```
$return = "download|";
for ($i; $i <= count($download); $i++) {
```

Also you should not use `<=` in:

```
for ($i; $i <=count($download)
```

it should be just `<`. This is because in an array of size `N`, `N` is not a valid index. The valid indices are `0` to `N-1`.

Also `ereg` family of function are deprecated as of `5.3.0` so its better you stop using them. You can use `preg_match` instead.

```
if (!eregi("avaxhome.ws|pixhost.info", $links))
```

can be written using `preg_match` as:

```
if (!preg_match("/avaxhome\.ws|pixhost\.info/i", $links))
```

Also note that the `.` in the regex needs to be escaped to treat it as a literal period.

[Working link](http://www.ideone.com/cDwvF)

Answer (score 0):

Try using php's `preg_match()` instead of `ereg()`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php